# Pentaho ETL service unavailable from local machine

Tags: pentaho-spoon

Pretty straightforward. I have a transformation that only checks if a certain URL is available. When I run said transformation from my local pentaho instance, it fails. When I then run it from a carte server on AWS, it works.
I can however just browse to the same site on my local machine and that works fine as well.

I asked and there were no firewall rules in place to stop me from doing this. The URL itself does not even matter (I could for example use stackoverflow.com as target and the symptoms would be equal).

I'm really stumped by this one. Open to all suggestions.

In case this matters, I run the CE version of Pentaho ETL 8.3

Comment: Please provide your transformation, so that we can have a look the issue. Theoretical there should not be any problem if you able to connect that url from your local machine

Comment: I could share the transformation but would have to mask the url and I don't see exactly how that would matter. In fact, easiest way to reproduce is simply create a REST client action with url. This issue was more of an "ow yeah I've had similar results" question.